# MYSQL IF THEN TRUE?

Tags: mysql

i have the default procedure like this:

`PROCEDURE PMS_Device_Update_Last_log_date ( Device_ID VARCHAR(255),option_value DATETIME)
BEGIN`

```
UPDATE PMS_Device
 SET PMS_Device.last_log_date = option_value 
WHERE PMS_Device.`Device_ID` = Device_ID;
```

how can i make:

`SET PMS_Device.last_log_date = option_value if option_value <"2014-04-01" then
option_value = "2014-04-01" 
if option_value > "2014-04-01" then SET PMS_Device.last_log_date = option_value`

im kinda lost, been reading online but couldn't make valid syntax

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should put it in a variable:

> SET @optionValue = (CASE x WHEN 1 THEN 'x' ELSE 'y' END);
>
> UPDATE x SET option_value = @optionValue WHERE a = b;

Comment: I edited the answer earlier and included parenthesis, did you try again?

Comment: `SET @optionValue = (CASE x WHEN option_value <= "2014-04-01" THEN 'option_value = "2014-04-01"' ELSE 'option_value' END);

UPDATE x SET option_value = @optionValue WHERE a = b;  `

Comment: when i use this command, the value option_value always up to date NOW in the system.

Answer (score 0):

You can frame your query as such if you want to do this in a single query:

```
IF option_value <= "2014-04-01"
BEGIN
      UPDATE        PMS_Device
      SET           last_log_date = "2014-04-01"
      WHERE         PMS_Device/Device_ID = Device_ID

END
ElSE   //case: where option_value is greater than "2014-04-01"
BEGIN
       UPDATE       PMS_Device
       SET          last_log_date = option_value  
       WHERE         PMS_Device/Device_ID = Device_ID
END
```

You can alternately, frame it using Case statement as such:

```
UPDATE        PMS_DEVICE
SET            last_log_date = 
               (case 
                   when     option_value < '2014-04-01'
                   then     '2014-04-01'
                end)
WHERE         device_ID = 1
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE        PMS_Device
      SET           PMS_Device.last_log_date = "2014-04' at line 7

Comment: `PROCEDURE PMS_Device_Update_Last_log_date ( Device_ID VARCHAR(255),option_value DATETIME)
BEGIN`
  
`IF option_value <= "2014-04-01"

      UPDATE        PMS_Device
      SET           PMS_Device.last_log_date = "2014-04-01"
      WHERE         PMS_Device.Device_ID = Device_ID

END
ELSE   //CASE: WHERE option_value IS greater THAN "2014-04-01"
BEGIN
       UPDATE       PMS_Device
       SET          PMS_Device.last_log_date = option_value  
       WHERE        PMS_Device.Device_ID = Device_ID
 
    END`

Answer (score 0):

your query format should be like below:

```
udapte tablename set columname = case when condition1 then answer1 when condition2 then answer2 else defaultvalue end
```